# If $G$ is a finite group, $g \in G$, and $\chi$ is a character of $G$, what are the definitions of "$\chi(g)$" and "$\overline{\chi(g)}$"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, characters

I'm looking at lemma $2.15$ on page $20$. [https://www.cefns.nau.edu/~falk/classes/511/Isaacs_Character_theory.pdf](https://www.cefns.nau.edu/%7Efalk/classes/511/Isaacs_Character_theory.pdf)

Comment: The bar denotes complex conjugation. You should know what $\chi(g)$ means if you know what a character is, right? Looking at the scan, it looks like it might be using a slightly different letter for the representation than the character, which if true is extremely unfortunate.

Comment: You should give a full presentation of the problem you want help with in the body of your Question.  In its current form the title gives some idea of what you want to ask about, but it is important to give Readers the full problem statement in the body to avoid confusion.

Comment: Having a hard time reading, but for finite groups a representation would be a way of mapping each group element to a matrix in a way that preserves the group structure. The character would then be the trace of the associated matrix (that is, the sum of the diagonal elements)

Answer (score 0):

$\chi(g)$ is the trace of the linear transformation $\rho(g)$. Since $G$ is finite, $g^n = 1$ for some $n$ ( works for $n = |G|$). Therefore $\rho(g)^n = I$ and so all of the eigenvalues of $\rho(g)$ are $n$-th roots of $1$. Now, $\chi(g)$ is the sum of these eigenvalues. From before,  any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $1$ has absolute value $1$, so $\bar \lambda = \lambda^{-1}$. Therefore
$$\overline{\chi(g)} = \overline {\sum \lambda_l} = \sum \overline {\lambda_l} = \sum \lambda_l^{-1} = \chi(g^{-1})$$